# "Map" remote internal IP to external IP

Tags: networking, port-forwarding

Basic scenario is simple: I need to access web UI (port `80`) on a server in a remote local network.

Example: remote server's internal IP is `a.b.c.d`, remote external IP is `w.x.y.z`.

I have 2 working options for this: 1) forward the server's port `80` to a public IP port `8080` using remote router (and then access web UI via `w.z.y.z:8080`), 2) forward remote server's port `80` to my localhost port `8080` using SSH tunnel `ssh -L 8080:localhost:80 w.x.y.z -N` (and then access web UI via `localhost:8080`, remote server's SSH port has been already forwarded to `w.x.y.z`). Both options work, I can access the web UI.

The problem: web UI renders all links using `a.b.c.d` as a hostname. So, when I click any link it goes to an IP to which I have no direct access locally and no knowledge of it.

Question: Is there a way to locally "map" `a.b.c.d` to `127.0.0.1` or to `w.x.y.z` (depending on which port forwarding method is used)?

Comment: What client OS, what kind of local router?

Comment: Windows 10 or Debian. For the purpose of the question I would like to consider no interaction with a local router. But if there are no pure OS options, then it is a Mikrotik with RouterOS.